# The Value expression for the text box specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-grouping, reportbuilder

I'm new with report builder so any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to sum a column in a report. in Most columns I can just wrap the row level expression with "Sum()" and it works. However, I have run into a few that give the following error.

Error:
The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox241’ specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.

Here is my row level expression that works.

```
    =Code.Divide(sum(Fields!WeeklyUnits.Value),sum(Fields!EstUnits.Value))
*
(Code.Divide(sum(Fields!EstHours.Value),sum(Fields!EstHours.Value,"Job")))
```

Here is my attempt to Sum the row level for the footer area (Doesn't Work)

```
=Sum(Code.Divide(sum(Fields!WeeklyUnits.Value),sum(Fields!EstUnits.Value))
*
(Code.Divide(sum(Fields!EstHours.Value),sum(Fields!EstHours.Value,"Job"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Reporting Services, since the function in custom code are used in row level expression, the argument for the function should be a static value on row level. All aggregation function are based on all values within a specified scope. So it can't be used as arguments in custom code.